# Previewing files in finder when hitting spacebar for different extensions

Tags: macos, finder, preview

I want to be able to preview files that are other than .txt, or .csv when I hit spacebar for example, in my chase this extension is .sql

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is the content of your .sql files? On my Mac the only .sql files are text files most of which have SQL statements. Quick Look (spacebar) shows the content as text.  Third party Quick Look plugins are usually found inside the applications that installed them.